# Angular Universal twice request

Tags: angular

I am working with Angular Universal and in the backend, I am using Node.js. Everything works fine but if I visit the site first time then my API is called twice.

[image: Browser Network]

In the first /load request the response is empty and in the second /laod response there are some data.

I am using a spinner on the client site and it looks strange. The site is loading data very quickly and after 1 second it is loading again.

Does someone have the same problem with Angular Universal?

Comment: Is the first one an `OPTIONS` method, and the second a `GET` method?

Comment: Those are xhr requests - your page requests should be type "document". Are you filtering your network requests? You are giving us a scant amount of information to troubleshoot this issue

Comment: As others have pointed out, XHR requests to a different domain will first fire an OPTIONS request, then the subsequent request. With Universal, unless you've implemented state transfer, you'll see requests fire once on the server side and again on the client side. Just something to watch out for.

Comment: yes, first one is options and second one is post

Comment: No solution for this kind of problem?